# How to link two table's pagenation in ant design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have two tables that I am working with in antdesign and what I want to do is if I click on page 2 for one of the pagenation tables, it changes the data for both tables. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll want to do is make your pagination controlled, so that both tables share the same pagination state and the same `onChange` event listener.

Here's a simple example of just controlling the [Pagination](https://ant.design/components/pagination/#components-pagination-demo-controlled) component via the Table's [pagination](https://ant.design/components/table/#pagination) prop:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Table } from "antd";
import data from "./data";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./styles.css";

const columns = [
  {
    title: "Title",
    dataIndex: "title",
    key: "title"
  },
  {
    title: "Body",
    dataIndex: "body",
    key: "body"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
  const handleChange = (page) => {
    setPage(page);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Table 1</h1>
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        pagination={{
          current: page,
          onChange: handleChange,
          total: data.length,
          showSizeChanger: false
        }}
        dataSource={data}
        rowKey="id"
      />
      <br />
      <h1>Table 2</h1>
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        pagination={{
          current: page,
          onChange: handleChange,
          total: data.length,
          showSizeChanger: false
        }}
        dataSource={data}
        rowKey="id"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Demo**:

[Antd shared pagination](https://wt7ne.csb.app/)

**Demo Code**:

[image: Edit Antd - Shared Pagination]